# Redirect in controllers spring3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring 3 you map urls as simply as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model)  {
    return "index";
}
```

Is it possible to make this kind of method to kinda redirect to another url like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model)  {
    return "second.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/second.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String second(Model model)  {
//put some staff in model
    return "second";
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to redirect - just call the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model)  {
    return second(model);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/second.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String second(Model model)  {
    //put some staff in model
    return "second";
}
```

This is one of the nice things about the annotation style; you can just chain your methods together.

If you *really* want a redirect, then you can return that as a view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public View index(Model model)  {
    return new RedirectView("second.html");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/second.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String second(Model model)  {
    //put some staff in model
    return "second";
}
```

Comment: I think your method has a security flaw. What if index() has  isAnonymous() authorization and second() has an "AUTHENTICATED" authorization? Wont invoking second() directly from index() cause an ugly situation? Its uglier since now the invocation of the guarded second() is from an internal method and not an external request so the "TRUST" factor will be much higher when invoking second()?

Comment: @skaffman but if controller method returns **ResponseEntity** for example ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes redirect will work. In index method, change last line  to `return "redirect:/second.html" ;`

**Edit**
context path and controller mapping are required. If DispatcherServlet is mapped to /ABC and request mapping for controller is /XYZ then you will have to write:
`return "redirect:/ABC/XYZ/second.html";`

Comment: but if controller method returns **ResponseEntity** for example ?